# How to use persistent names in LILO?

Tags: lilo

I have two SATA drives, but their names `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` are chosen randomly by Linux.

How can I correctly set up LILO? How can I put a stable reference to the hard drives in `lilo.conf`?

**ADDED.** Can I use udev's names (like /dev/disk/by-id/*) in lilo.conf? LILO doesn't read lilo.conf at each boot, but only once on setup MBR when I run 'lilo' without arguments. At this stage udev names are available. But how do LILO store information about disks to MBR and boot-files?

I use dual-boot with Windows, but NTFS disks have no UUID. I want to use udev's id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use UUIDs to identify the disks and boot via that.

Run `blkid` on your machine to get a list of drives and their UUIDs.

Then modify your `lilo.conf` and use `root=UUID=<DISK UUID>` rather than `root=/dev/sda` etc.

Assumes you have a kernel version that supports UUIDs - check first by looking in `/dev/disk/by-uuid`.  You could also use `LABEL=`.

Comment: Thank you, but I have additional questions. I've updated the main question.

Comment: I dont think it matters - `lilo.conf` will be read once when installing and whether it contains root entries by UUID or by dev doesnt matter - its the kernel that understands the "UUID=" options, not lilo.  There are even scripts to automatically convert your `lilo.conf` to using UUIDs, like [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/lilo-uuid-diskid.8.html) one